# Syntax error from handling write to new file from a list

Tags: python

So I want to write a program that writes 10 random numbers into a text file:

```
import random
SIZE = 10

for i in range (0, SIZE, 1):
    y = random.randrange(0,100)

x = open("data.txt","w+")
x.write("\n")
for i in range (0, SIZE, 1):
    x.write("Results: %d", %(y))

x.close()
```

I got a syntax error in the "%(y)". But I have no idea what causes it.

Comment: Leave out the comma. `x.write("Results: %d" % y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that % is an operator that is used between strings, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). This should work:

```
import random
SIZE = 10

for i in range (0, SIZE, 1):
    y = random.randrange(0,100)

x = open("data.txt","w+")
x.write("\n")
for i in range (0, SIZE, 1):
    x.write("Results: %d" %  y)

x.close()
```

Also, `range(0, SIZE, 1)` can be replaced by `range(SIZE)`, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges).

You can use the syntax `with open("data.txt", "w+") as f` that is preferred according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

```
import random
SIZE = 10

for i in range(SIZE):
    y = random.randrange(0, 100)

with open("data.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write("\n")
    for i in range(SIZE):
        f.write("Results: %d" % y)
```

Also, I'm not sure about what you are doing, isn't the correct code:

```
import random
SIZE = 10

with open("data.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write("\n")
    for i in range(SIZE):
        y = random.randrange(0, 100)
        f.write("Results: %d" % y)
```

Also, be aware that `write` doesn't put any newline, maybe you want to write `"Results: %d\n"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. Main problem here is `%` sign used improperly, I also suggest some code edits that is opening file using `with` statement ensures it closes every time so this is a best practice.

```
import random
    SIZE = 10

    with open("data.txt", 'w+') as x:
        x.write("\n")
        for i in range (0, SIZE, 1):
            y = random.randrange(0,100)
            x.write("Results: %d" %  y)
```